# Why is my Bootstrap 3 carousel not sliding properly?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I created a carousel using Twitter Bootstrap 3 and I cannot get it to work correctly. The slides seem to Overlay each other and it does not cycle through them all. Checked for coding errors but found none. Here is a Jsfiddle with my code: (http://jsfiddle.net/N6Y4D/)

Or here:

```
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner">

            <div class="item-active">
                <img src="img/slide1.png" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; display: block"/>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Heading text</h1>
                        <p>Description</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/slide2.png" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; display: block"/>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Heading text</h1>
                        <p>Description</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/slide3.png" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; display: block"/>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Heading text</h1>
                        <p>Description</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>

        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>


    </div>

        <script src= "js/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
        <script src= "js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Probably not the answer, but `<div class="item-active">` should be `<div class="item active">` (with a space between item and active, not a hyphen).

Comment: @OllyHodgson That was the answer actually. Removing the hyphen solved the issue!

Answer (score 3):

Here is complete code for it.. Inside the 'carousel-inner' you have written as 'item-active' , it should be 'item active' Both are separate classes.

```
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner">

            <div class="item active"> // error was occurring here it should item active not item-active
                <img src="img/slide1.png" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; display: block"/>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Heading text</h1>
                        <p>Description</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/slide2.png" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; display: block"/>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Heading text</h1>
                        <p>Description</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/slide3.png" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; display: block"/>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Heading text</h1>
                        <p>Description</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>

        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>


    </div>
```